# About lower bound in Scala

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and have a question regarding lower bound.

I have a class:

```
class Queue[+T] {
    def enqueue[U>:T](x : U) = new Queue[U]()
}

class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit
class Another
```

What I found is that, for a Queue of any type, e.g.:

```
    val q1 = new Queue[Fruit]
```

All the three lines below will pass compile

```
    q1.enqueue(new Apple)
    q1.enqueue(new Orange)
    q1.enqueue(new Another)
```

My question is: if we use lower bound to define U must be a super type of T, in the lines above, Apple is clearly not a super type of Fruit, how can it be passed to the enqueue function?

The "Another" class is not in the fruit hierachy at all, how can it be used in the enqueue function?

Please help me out with this.

Regards
Kevin

Comment: Imagine the colon `>:` as an equals `>=`

Comment: i also had the same question. the answers given below clarified my doubt. you should accept an answer below.

Answer (score 13):

If you take a look of what your new queues return:

```
scala>  q1.enqueue(new Apple)
res0: Queue[Fruit] = Queue@17892d5

scala> q1.enqueue(new Orange)
res1: Queue[Fruit] = Queue@bdec44

scala> q1.enqueue(new Another)
res2: Queue[ScalaObject] = Queue@104bce3
```

What you said that specifically U should be a super-type of T (or T). This means Another works great because ScalaObject is the most specific super-type of both Another and Fruit.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: if we use lower bound to define U must be a super type of T, in the lines above, Apple is clearly not a super type of Fruit, how can it be passed to the enqueue function?

But `new Apple` is a `Fruit`, and `Fruit` is a supertype of `Fruit`. So in your case `U` is `Fruit`, and a `Queue[Fruit]` is returned. And `new Another` is a `ScalaObject`, which is also a supertype of `Fruit`...